# How to call action sheet from Facebook iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, soundcloud

When I tap on some Sound Cloud content on FB timeline, FB iPhone app shows Action Sheet with these options:

1. Open Web page
2. Install Sound Cloud app

How do I call action sheet on Facebook content in a Facebook iOS app? Was that a special feature FB gave Sound Cloud?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

You may check Facebook developer documentation :

> One of the most interesting aspects of sharing to Facebook from your
>   app is that when people engage with the news feed stories posted from
>   your app, those stories can send people to your app or your app's App
>   Store page, driving traffic and app installs. You can implement this
>   behavior using App Links.
>
> When you set up App Links, you can control what happens when someone
>   taps on one of the links shared through your app or on the story
>   attribution (name of your app) in one of the Open Graph stories shared
>   through your app. If your app has web content, people will be
>   redirected to a web view of that content. If your app is installed
>   there may be an open button that launches your iOS app. if your app
>   isn't installed, there will be an install option to direct people to
>   your app's App Store page. If your app is mobile-only (no web content)
>   then tapping the shared link will either direct people to your app (if
>   it's installed) or to your app's App Store page (if your app isn't
>   installed)

[App Links on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios)

[Sharing on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)